# Using SSL server authentication with Savon

Tags: ruby, http, soap, savon, httpi

I'm connecting to a biztalk SOAP API, and I've been given a public cert from the server to use to connect using ssl server authentication.

I'm using: Ruby 1.9.2, Curb (0.7.15), Savon (0.9.1) HTTPi (0.9.2)

I can't seem to get it to work properly, but it works from the command line with CURL:

```
curl --cacert /path/to/cert https://raadeeraa
```

but I can't work out the combination of how to get it to work with Savon, HTTPi and Curb.

This goes through:

```
http.auth.ssl.ca_cert_file = '/path/to/cert'
http.auth.ssl.verify_mode = :peer
```

But this also goes through, so I don't think it's working properly:

```
http.auth.ssl.ca_cert_file = '/complete/load/of/nonsnse'
http.auth.ssl.verify_mode = :peer
```

This fails with a ssl cert error:

```
http.auth.ssl.ca_cert_file = '/path/to/cert'
http.auth.ssl.verify_mode = :none

`cert=': undefined method `rindex' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

So I specify a cert as well:

```
http.auth.ssl.ca_cert_file = '/path/to/cert'
http.auth.ssl.cert_file = '/path/to/cert'
http.auth.ssl.verify_mode = :none

rails3.0.4/gems/httpi-0.9.2/lib/httpi/adapter/curb.rb:29:in `http_post': Problem with the local SSL certificate (Curl::Err::SSLCertificateError)
```

Please don't think I'm posting without reading, I've read all these pages and can't find a solution. Well, you'll have to take my word for it, I can only put up two hyperlinks :-)

http://rubydoc.info/gems/httpi/0.9.2/frames

https://github.com/rubiii/httpi

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm drilling down, and I've got httpclient to work on it's own as I'd expect, here's the code

<pre><code>require 'httpclient'

client = HTTPClient.new
client.ssl_config.set_trust_ca('certificate off the server')

url = "https://doodaa"
resp = client.get(url)
puts resp.content
puts resp.status</code></pre>

If I alter that certificate, or use another one, it fails, as it should.

How to represent that code in savon is the next question.

I'm going to remove curb and go with httpclient from now on, at least I know that works in this instance

Comment: Here's some more details  http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1490195#new

Comment: I found the problem [link](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1490195#992527)